# What would cause Sitecore and Solr to not talk to each other?

Tags: solr, docker

I'm running Sitecore 8.2 Update 4 with Solr 5.5 (running inside of a Linux Docker container). I'm trying to get Sitecore to tell Solr to populate the indexes. Here's my setup:

1. Downloaded the Solr 5.5 docker image.
2. Copied a valid Solr Schema file (taken from our test environment) to the appropriate configs folder.
3. Changed the solrconfig.xml file to use `ClassicIndexSchemaFactory`.
4. Populated my cors using a powershell script which has proven to work fine in other environments.
5. Using `ShowConfig.aspx` I was able to verify that Sitecore is pointing to my local instance of Solr.
6. Verified that Solr is running and accessible from the address that Sitecore is looking at.
7. Verified that Sitecore is running in SOLR mode and not Lucene mode.

Now, when I try to run the re-indexing process, I get this screen:

[image: Indexing Manager Empty]

I've checked the Sitecore Logs, and all it says is this:

```
12116 16:41:25 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): Rebuild indexes from Indexing Manager: sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #7 16:41:25 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index
ManagedPoolThread #7 16:41:25 INFO  Job ended: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index (units processed: )
```

And in SOLR, I'm seeing no logs whatsoever. 
[image: No SOLR Errors Logged]

I've also verified that I don't have any documents in my master database, which has over 70,000 items in it.
[image: No documents]

I'm not sure where I should start looking for errors.

**Update:**
Thanks to the comments, I'm able to see the following errors in my crawling.log file. I'm not sure what they mean because my SOLR instance is up and running and available, but at least it's something to go on. Here's the log:

> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_analytics_index'
>   index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_core_index' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_master_index' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_web_index' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master' index. Registering the index
>   for re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web' index. Registering the index for
>   re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master' index. Registering the index
>   for re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web' index. Registering the index for
>   re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_testing_index' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_suggested_test_index' index. Registering the index for
>   re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_fxm_master_index' index. Registering the index for
>   re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_fxm_web_index' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'sitecore_list_index' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'social_messages_master' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'social_messages_web' index. Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to
>   SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  Failed to initialize 'mediaframework_ooyala_index' index. Registering the index for
>   re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available ...
>
> 8316 10:15:02 WARN  DONE

Comment: Do you have errors in your "Crawling" log?

Comment: What url do you have configured?

Comment: Firewall? Turn logging up to Full in Sitecore config

Comment: Did you clear your target environment of any leftover *Lucene.config files?  Leaving them around can cause all sorts of upset, even if you rmain config setup now points to SOLR.

Comment: Does your SOLR log show anything?

Comment: Make sure the config file `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master` is enabled and the config `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Master` is disabled on your instance's `App_Config\Include` folder.

Comment: In your core.properties file does your name match your index name?

Comment: @PeteNavarra I've updated my question with the information from the crawling log file.

Comment: @MichaelWest I am using the standard SOLR port (localhost:8983). I've verified that the URL is working as I'm able to navigate to the URL from my browser.

Comment: @KeithVanderVeen You said you're using Docker images..  I know very little about docker, but assume it just sets up VM's.  Are you using two different dockers for Solr and Sitecore? If so, I would make sure you have the firewalls completely turned off on both.   Basically, Something is preventing communication from Sitecore to Solr.  My hunch is that it's configuration based... maybe the Service Base Address for Solr is incorrect some how.  Maybe it's a hostname issue or host file issue.

Comment: So the value you set for `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` is `http://localhost:8983/solr`?

Comment: Yes @MichaelWest, when I look at showconfig.aspx, I see this entry: `<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" value="http://localhost:8983/solr" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config"/>`

Comment: @PeteNavarra I am using Docker for my SOLR instance, but running Sitecore on my physical hardware. I might try loading up SOLR on my physical hardware and see if that resolves anything.

Comment: @PeteNavarra I installed a local version of SOLR (not using Docker) and got the same result. :(

Comment: This post suggests that your `Schema.xml` may need to be regenerated http://www.sitecorebear.com/sitecore-not-rebuilding-indexes/, would you be able to drop your `Schema.xml` in the post?

Comment: This seems the SOLR connection detail in default index config is not working. Did you checked from the server / machine that the SOLR URL is accessible or not?

Comment: Did you find the cause?

Comment: No, I never discovered the solution. I just gave up trying to run Sitecore in a Docker Container. I'm hoping that both Sitecore and Docker for Windows will eventually get to a point where this will be possible. It might be about time to try it again. This post is fairly old now, and I haven't come back around to it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds very odd, if you were using Solr Cloud then might have been Zookeeper was down when SOLR started up.
Or you might have missed out creating the SOLR aliases. 
Don't see a mention of SolrCloud or Zookeeper though.

Other than checking collections and configs match up.

To see what is going on, install Fiddler, change your sitecore app pool to run as your Windows user (processes running under same user go through Fiddler by default), change the solr connection string to localhost.:8983 (extra dot makes it go through fiddler proxy)
Restart sitecore, see what requests are being attempted to Solr and what response is returned.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Recently encountered the same `Registering the index for re-initialization once connection to SOLR becomes available` with an additional `Error handling 'status' action` in the crawling log.  After double checking all our configs, we found that we had inadvertently used a `ServiceBaseAddress` from another integration environment (old variable from a cloned VSTS release) and the two sites were fighting for contention (I can only assume constant rebuilds and updates).  Simply cloning the resource to a new VM and updating the address resolved the issue.  May not be the exact issue in your case but hope it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config, for each index core,

```
<index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
  <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Solr.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Providers.Solr</patch:attribute>
  <param desc="core">testytesty_sitecore_web_index</param>
  <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
   <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific</patch:attribute>
   </crawler>
  </locations>
```

This line:

```
<param desc="core">testytesty_sitecore_web_index</param>
```

Points to the index on the Solr server.

Whereas this line:

```
<index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
```

I'm guessing points to the local reference.

Changing the first should help.

There may still be bugs after this step, but hopefully different ones